# Why does PHP convert a string with the letter E into a number?

Tags: php, string, type-conversion, string-comparison

Why does the following statement return `true`?

```
"608E-4234" == "272E-3063"
```

I have also tried this with single quotes around the strings. The only way I can get it to evaulate to `false` is by using the `===` operator instead of `==`

My guess is PHP is treating it as some sort of equation but it seems a bit of a strange one.

Can anybody elaborate?

Comment: echo 608E-4234 = 0; echo 272E-3063 = 0; 0==0

Comment: [PHP is weakly/loosely typed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467871/what-is-a-loosely-typed-language). Depending on context, what you claim is a string, is something else in fact. So better use `===` if you want to compare strings. Know your operators.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`"608E-4234"` is the [float number format](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), so they will cast into number when they compares.

`608E-4234` and `272E-3063` will both be `float(0)` because they are too small.

For `==` in php,

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
> **numerical strings**, then each string is converted to a number and the
> comparison performed numerically.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

***Attention:***

***What about the behavior in javascript which also has both `==` and `===`?***

The answer is the behavior is different from PHP. In javascript, if you compare two value with same type, `==` is just same as `===`, so type cast won't happen for compare with two same type values.

***In javascript:***

```
608E-4234 == 272E-3063 // true
608E-4234 == "272E-3063" // true
"608E-4234" == 272E-3063 // true
"608E-4234" == "272E-3063" // false (Note: this is different from PHP)
```

So in javascript, when you know the type of the result, you could use `==` instead of `===` to save one character.

For example, `typeof` operator always returns a string, so you could just use

`typeof foo == 'string'` instead of `typeof foo === 'string'` with no harm.

Comment: Important bit from the manual about [operator comparations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): *If you compare a number with a string **or the comparison involves numerical strings**, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.*

Comment: See also: http://phpsadness.com/sad/47

Comment: `Numerical Strings` -> [What.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FlatWhat) Doesn't it make it even harder to write secure applications in PHP.

Comment: @phresnel Not really.  Use `===`, which should be taught in PHP 101 for "compare these values exactly".  It's only confusing to people that come from languages without fuzzy comparison, like C and Java.

Comment: @lzkata: That's for sure, but I wouldn't have expected that when I compare two string literals, such things may happen. In other words: I wouldn't have expected that that when I compare two operands of the exact same type, there's a need for the `===` operator. Of course the documentation mentions it, but the doc is also [fuzzy](http://web.archive.org/web/20080228051801/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [quite fuzzy](http://web.archive.org/web/20030402111048/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Testing floats for equality?  The thought gives me dyspepsia.

Comment: @phresnel Check the JavaScript's ==, it's different from php! So I think this behavior in php is not normal knowledge :)

Answer (score 22):

PHP uses IEEE 754 for floats, and your numbers are so small that they evalue to 0.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

```
Name        Common name         Base    Digits  E min   E max   
binary32    Single precision        2   23+1    −126    +127        
binary64    Double precision        2   52+1    −1022   +1023
```

Comment: But he wasn't comparing floats, he's comparing strings. So what PHP uses for floats **should** be irrelevant

Comment: @jalf php is loosely typed and is converting the values behind the scenes == is evil if you are not familiar with language, if he wanted to compare them as strings he needed to use === or strcmp as others have mentioned.

Comment: @stoj yes, but my point is that this answer does not answer the question: it describes the fp representation used by PHP, but it does not state the important fact that "if your string looks like a FP value, it will be converted into a FP value".

Answer (score 16):

I think that PHP reads this as a scientific syntax, which will be translated as:

```
608 x 10^-4234 == 272 x 10^-3063
```

PHP interprets this as being `0 = 0`.

Answer (score 11):

PHP is comparing those strings as floating point numbers, and they both are zero, so you **MUST** use the `===` operator,

Comment: As I said in my answer, that is because the two strings are compared as floating point numbers, which are rounded to zero, hence they're **equal** but not **identical**

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to answer. 
If you are using "===", you also check with the type instead of the value.
If you are using "==", you just check the value is the same or not.

you can reference to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) and [here](http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/web_development/php/tips_and_tricks/difference_between_equal_and_identical_comparison_operators_php.php).

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have noted this, but the PHP manual has made this explicit now. [PHP sees any string with an `E` bounded by numbers as scientific notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php)

> EXPONENT_DNUM    (({LNUM} | {DNUM}) [eE][+-]? {LNUM})

As you can see, this is case insensitive (`E` or `e`). Where this becomes a gotcha is in weak type string comparisons

```
var_dump("2E1" == "020"); // true
```

`2E1` is really `2 * (10 ^ 1)`, and that works out to 20. Insert any other letter there and it will return the expected `false`. From the question

```
"608E-4234" == "272E-3063"
```

That works out to

```
608 * (10 ^ -4234) == 272 * (10 ^ -3063)
```

Neither number can be represented by PHP (as [JvdBerg noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12598515/2370483)), so they are converted to `0`

Answer (score 3):

This is what it is seeing:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=608E-4234&dataset=
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=272E-3063

As they don't fit into the variable, they both equate to 0, or whatever default value php chooses, and therefore are equivalent.