# can === and != be used interchangably?

Tags: php

Can the relational operator === (used for identical) be used interchangeably with the != operator" and get the same results? Or will I eventually run into issues later down the road when I do larger programs?

I know I will get the same results in the example below, will this always be true?

```
//example 1  
   <?php
        $a = 1; //integer
        $b = '1'; //string
        if ($a === $b) {     
            echo 'Values and types are same'; 
        }
        else {
            echo 'Values and types are not same';
        }
    ?> 

 // example 2
    <?php
        $a = 1; //integer
        $b = '1'; //string
        if ($a != $b) {     
            echo 'Values and types are not same'; 
        }
        else {
            echo 'Values and types are same';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? PHP's operators are confusing enough as they are.

Comment: != is not equal, you need !== to have not equal and not same type. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Check this question and you will not like to use `==` or `!=`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598407/php-expresses-two-different-strings-to-be-the-same

Comment: I see this being helpful when validating forms and checking if user has special privileges to see specifice pages based on specific database fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is, no, you can't interchange them because they check for different things. They are not equivalent operators.

You'll want to use !==

It basically means both values being compared must be of the same type.

When you use ==, the values being compared are typecast if needed.

As you know, === checks the types also.

When you use !=, the values are also typecast, whereas !== checks the values and type, strictly.

Comment: Couple seconds faster than me :). That is your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially asking whether `!($a != $b)` will always be identical to `$a === $b`. The simple answer is: no. `!($a != $b)` can be boiled down to `$a == $b`, which is obviously not the same as `$a === $b`:

```
php > var_dump(!('0' != 0));
bool(true)

php > var_dump('0' === 0);
bool(false)
```

`!==` is obviously the opposite of `===`, so `!($a !== $b)` will always be identical to `$a === $b`.

Comment: It's asking `if ($a === $b) true; else false;` vs. `if ($a != $b) false; else true;`, which is what I'm explaining.