# PHP: Switch weird behavior

Tags: php, logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP expresses two different strings to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598407/php-expresses-two-different-strings-to-be-the-same)

I have a problem understanding what's causes this weird behavior in a switch case instruction.

The code is this:

```
<?php
$myKey = "0E9";

switch ($myKey) {
    case "0E2":
        echo "The F Word";
        break;
    case "0E9":
        echo "This is the G";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Nothing here";
        break;
}
?>
```

The result of this instruction should be **This is the G**

Well, not so. always returns **The F Word**

If we reverse the **0E9** left instructions for the beginning and try to find the value **0E2**

```
<?php
$myKey = "0E2";

switch ($myKey) {
    case "0E9":
        echo "The G String";
    break;
    case "0E2":
        echo "The F Word";
        break;       
    default:
        echo "Nothing here";
        break;
}
?>
```

Now returns always **This is the G**

**0E2** and **0E9** values ​​are not interpreted as text? Those Values ​​are reserved?

Someone can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"0E2" == "0E9"` is `true` because they are **numerical strings**.

Note: **switch use loose comparision**.

Check this question: [PHP expresses two different strings to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598407/php-expresses-two-different-strings-to-be-the-same).

Comment: totally true. I did not know that the comparison of switch was made that way. [facepalm] Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Numeric strings such as these are equal to each other .. always.  Unfortunately, there is no way to force an equivalence comparison via `switch`.  You just have to use `if`:

```
if ($myKey === '0E9') {
   echo 'g';
}
else if ($myKey === '0E2') {
   echo 'f';
}
else {
   echo "Nothing here";
}
```

You could also trim the leading zero, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, Every day you learn something new