# Why md5('240610708') is equal to md5('QNKCDZO')?

Tags: php, md5

```
var_dump(md5('240610708') == md5('QNKCDZO'));
```

**Output:**

```
bool(true)
```

**Example:** http://3v4l.org/2vrMi

Comment: use "===" and you get `false`

Comment: They are not the same (php is probably converting them to integers and doing integer comparison → use `===` instead)

Comment: I can't answer here, but it seems like your both parts has `0^(x)`, where `x` is next part of hash. This way, `0e123` is intepretating as int: `0^123`.
So, `0^y==0^x` for any `x,y>0`. So, you got output `true`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`md5('240610708')` 's result is  `0e462097431906509019562988736854`.

`md5('QNKCDZO')` 's result is `0e830400451993494058024219903391`.

They are both **float number format strings** (**numerical strings**), and if you use `==` in php, when compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Both of the strings are converted to `0` when compared with `==`, if you want to compare them as string, remember to use `===`(**strict comparison**) instead.

See: [PHP expresses two different strings to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598407/php-expresses-two-different-strings-to-be-the-same/12598484#12598484)

Comment: Hashes should also, in a lot of cases, also be compared in constant-time (especially in the context of a MAC to authenticate a ciphertext). So the == bug isn't critical, since you should never be using == for security-sensitive hash comparisons.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski really? What does it really give the attacker to learn the size of the prefix of a constant pseudorandom string A with a pseudorandom string B?

Comment: If you know M and HMAC(M, K), and you want to find a valid HMAC(M', K) for M', you can send your M' and use timing information to build a valid HMAC output without needing to ever know K.

Comment: There is a good article about this security vulnerability and it also explains how to bypass strcmp by using an array: https://marcosvalle.github.io/ctf/php/2016/05/12/php-comparison-vlun.html

Answer (score 18):

You need to use the type-sensitive comparison operator `===`.

The hashes evaluate to `0e462097431906509019562988736854` and `0e830400451993494058024219903391`, respectively. When you use `==`, each is converted to a numeric representation because of the `e` (scientific notation), so they each become `0`. `0 == 0` is true.

On the other hand, this:

```
md5('240610708') === md5('QNKCDZO')
```

returns `false` because the *string* values are different. `===` forces type-sensitive comparison.