# How to compare md5 password php

Tags: php

I need to check if `$user_entered_pass`idential to `$hash_val` . Please help me?

```
    <?php
    $mypass = "Rainbow";
    $hash_val = md5($mypass);

    echo $hash_val; //always 32 characters

    $user_entered_pass = "rainbow";
?>
```

Comment: Look into existing libraries for password hashing

Comment: md5 is now considered vulnerable. I'd suggest switching to password_hash which is explain here http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hash $user_entered_pass and compare, I use this method.

```
<?php
    $mypass = "Rainbow";
    $hash_val = md5($mypass);

    echo $hash_val; //always 32 characters

    $user_entered_pass = "rainbow";

    if(md5($user_entered_pass) == $hash_val){
      //The passwords are equal
    }
?>
```

Comment: That's not correct. You should use `===` and not `==`, because the latter treats strings starting with `0e` as equal to `0`.

Comment: Congrats friend, get information about PHP in the year 2016, when I wrote this answer.

Comment: Sure. Here's a guy from 2014 saying this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22140266/13885961

Answer (score 2):

Convert user entered password to md5 and then check.
`$user_entered_pass_has = md5($user_entered_pass)`
Then check for equality.

Answer (score 2):

Compare it with the identical operator `===`, e.g.:

```
if ($hashFromDatabase === md5($userEnteredPasswort)) {
    // authenticated ...
}
```

However, I strongly recommend you not to use md5 as hashing algorithm. Check out this answer here: [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Moreover, I recommend you using the new password hashing API from PHP (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`).